# Как просмотреть байт код класса в рантайме?

Tags: jvm, java, runtime

Как получить байт код класса, это понятно, можно при помощи идеи или же дефолтными средствами

> javap -c -s -verbose и путь к классу.

А вот как посмотреть код над которым jvm выполнила оптимизации, который крутится в рантайме я не знаю. Возможно ли такое вообще, если да, то как это сделать?

Comment: Оптимизации выполняет JIT-компилятор. Так что если хотите посмотреть на фактически выполняющийся код, придётся смотреть на ассемблерный листинг.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно увидеть код, который генерируется в рантайме jit компилятором. Это возможно сделать, например, при помощи программы [`jit watcher`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/jitwatch)
Из возможностей этой программы:

- просмотр сгенерированного кода после каждого этапа компиляции
- просмотр байт кода и асемблеровского кода
- удобная навигация по коду и определения соотвествия между java, байт кодом и асемблеровским кодом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]